# Ford full sized Bronco front and rear rack diner idea?

Tags: ford, swap, crown-victoria, bronco

I would love to build my own Frankenstein out of a 68 Ford and Crown Vic, swap their racks for the front, and a Lincoln Mark 8 for the rear. But a good donor body is hard to find where I'm at. What about a Ford Bronco full size? It's wheelbase is 104.7" where a Crown Vic's front rack is 114.4" and the Lincoln MkVIII is 113 inches.

Is my idea possible? If it requires custom one off rims to deal with adjusting for negative and positive offset then fine. Or perhaps a different donor idea for racks all together.